# How do you share changes made with Management Center between WebSphere Commerce developers?

Tags: websphere, websphere-commerce

Example:
I added new Marketing spot on some JSP page. I need to change JSP and create this spot in management center. Changes in JSP are shared through CVS, but what about Marketing Spot? It is stored somewhere in database, but I could not find solution to export this content properly neither with WCBD tool nor manually. What would you do in this case?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have three options:

1. Manually re-create the requisite spot configuration in the other database.
2. Use a shared database for the development team.  It is not as bad as it sounds, I have had my team use it in the past.
3. Use the export/import functionality.  This is not recommended as the time you will spend trying to analyze all tables and dependencies may not be worth it.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to share across development instances?  A shared dev instance is a good option as mentioned above.  Also taking advantage of stageprop and staging copy could be a good answer.  A quick trip to infocenter shows:

http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wchelp/v7r0m0/topic/com.ibm.commerce.admin.doc/refs/rsscopy.htm

If you use the merchant table option it will copy changes to a store.  Using this utility may require turning on stage logging in the staglog table.

More on that here:

http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wchelp/v7r0m0/topic/com.ibm.commerce.admin.doc/concepts/csstagingserver.htm